# (In general) should ASP.NET MVC be used as the backend for an Angular app?

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc

Most of my experience is in the Java stack/community. But I was just moved onto a brand new project for a brand new webapp that will use a .NET stack.

One of my superiors suggested that we implement this brand new webapp using an Angular frontend and a ASP.NET MVC backend. I know that it is *possible* for an Angular frontend to use an ASP.NET MVC backend. But I also know that one of the main draws of ASP.NET MVC is the Razor view engine, which we would not be using. Furthermore, Wikipedia says that ASP.NET MVC is discontinued. Therefore my question - is it *recommended* to use ASP.NET MVC as the backend for an Angular app?

Comment: I would more suggest WebApi: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/apis

Comment: I'd also add that you should be looking at ASP.NET Core (upon which you can implement a WebApi solution) for projects moving forward as that's the long-term supported platform moving forward: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

As to the question of whether that's a good pairing with your Angular site, that veers into "opinion-based". Certainly it's possible but whether it's a good fit is particular to your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, using angular as a front end and asp.net mvc as a backend is a good combination.
You can use asp.net **web api** (with **EFCore** + **SQlServer** database )to build your rest services and use angular to consume it in frontend.

Comment: I think some of my confusion came from misunderstanding the difference (or lack of difference) between ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET Web API, and ASP.NET Core. After looking at this longer, I can confirm that although ASP.NET Core is more tightly integrated with Angular, Angular definitely can be integrated into an ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Web API app.